# Connect python script to node js using pythonshell package in node js

Tags: python, node.js

I created a python program to **scrape** content from wikipedia page. I want to display this **scraped** data on localserver with node js server using express node js having pythonshell package. This is my code for Wiki.py(python program that i want to print on local host) and start.js(node js program to upload on local server) but it prints on terminal only but doesnot send any data to local host. Task is to do in this manner specifically.

**Wiki.py Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will_Smith').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')

heading = soup.find('h1',{'id':'firstHeading'}).text
print(heading)
print()

for item in soup.select("#mw-content-text"):
    required_data = [p_item.text for p_item in item.select("p")][3:6]
    print('\n'.join(required_data))
```

**Start.js: Node js code:**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  var myPythonScriptPath = 'Wiki1.py';
  const {PythonShell} = require("python-shell");
  var pyshell = new PythonShell(myPythonScriptPath);

  pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
    console.log(message);
});
})
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port 
${port}!`))
```

Comment: after your console.log write, res.send(message) to send data on hitting http://localhost:3000.

Comment: so I've added app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`)) but its not giving me any data..just data could not be received. Can you please elaborate your answer.Thank you.

Comment: I have elaborated the above point in my answer. Please check if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: so i added res.send(message);....but it only executes" heading = soup.find('h1',{'id':'firstHeading'}).text
print(heading)
print()"
and gives heading Will smith..i.e. heading part but while executing second line of code it gives Error::
_http_outgoing.js:485
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use node.js child_process module

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const app = express()
const port = 3000
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const pyProg = spawn('python', ['script.py']);
    pyProg.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
        res.send(data.toString())
    });

})
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port 
${port}!`))
```

script.py

```
print('data return from python')
print('data return from python')
print('data return from python')
print('data return from python')
print('data return from python')
```

Comment: I have just edit the index.js file with express . You have to add sys.stdout.flush() under your last print command in order to send data to node.js

Comment: Try again and delete the last line of code ''sys.stdout.flush()"

Comment: Download the sample app from github  https://github.com/petranb2/node_python

Answer (score 0):

So, If all you are looking for is sending the "string" message back as response to the API then,

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const myPythonScriptPath = 'wiki.py';
  const {PythonShell} = require("python-shell");
  const pyshell = new PythonShell(myPythonScriptPath);
  let string = ''

  pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
      console.log(message);
      string+=message
  });

  pyshell.end(function (err,code,signal) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('The exit code was: ' + code);
      console.log('The exit signal was: ' + signal);
      console.log('finished', string);
      res.status(200).send(string)
  });  
})
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port 
${port}!`))
```

Comment: I executed this code but it only executes "heading = soup.find('h1',{'id':'firstHeading'}).text print(heading) print()" and gives heading Will smith..i.e. heading part but while executing second line of code it gives Error:: _http_outgoing.js:485 throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');

Comment: I have edited the answer, Please check if its what you were looking.